# Trust Mechansim in Wireless Sensor Networks

Tags: wireless, ns2

I want to implement Trust Mechanism In Wireless Sensor Networks and then calculate the residual energy of nodes.

Can anyone please help. I want to implement Subject Trust Logic as Trust Mechanism.

Comment: This question is too broad. What did you try so far?

Comment: I have created a topology in NS2 and calculated the energy of node initially. Now i want ti implement Trust on those nodes.

Comment: May be usable : "How to add trust table in NS2" : http://durgeshkshirsagar.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-add-trust-table-in-ns2.html

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for the help. Letme go through that link.